# What is exact difference between SessionLocaleResolver and FixedLocaleResolver

Tags: java, spring-boot, localization, internationalization

I am reading about localization and internationalization concepts in Java.

Default `Locale` can be both `SessionLocaleResolver` and `FixedLocaleResolver`.

Setting `SessionLocaleResolver` as default:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
    SessionLocaleResolver r = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    r.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return r;
}
```

Setting `FixedLocaleResolver` as default:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
    FixedLocaleResolver r = new FixedLocaleResolver();
    r.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return r;
}
```

Can someone tell me what is the exact difference between those two and how does that difference affect an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what we can find out from the Spring documentation

**FixedLocaleResolver:**

> LocaleResolver implementation that always returns a fixed default
> locale and optionally time zone. Default is the current JVM's default
> locale.

**SessionLocaleResolver:**

> LocaleResolver implementation that uses a locale attribute in the
> user's session in case of a custom setting, with a fallback to the
> specified default locale or the request's accept-header locale. This
> is most appropriate if the application needs user sessions anyway,
> i.e. when the HttpSession does not have to be created just for storing
> the user's locale. The session may optionally contain an associated
> time zone attribute as well; alternatively, you may specify a default
> time zone.

Usually when you want to enable internationalization feature in your Spring Boot application you want to define a second @Bean in your configuration class:

```
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}
```

This together with the **SessionLocaleResolver** will enable a possibility for a client to send any request with a "lang" parameter to your application, let's say for example to:

> localhost:8080/public/api/?lang=pt_BR

Which in result will set the session locale attribute from default en_US to pt_BR, which then can be used to change the displayed language on the webpage.

On the other hand if you will use **FixedLocaleResolver** and leave LocaleChangeInterceptor as is, then when the client will send a request with "lang" parameter, the server will respond with Http Status 500 Code - Internal Server Error, and you will see in your console that exception was thrown:

> UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change fixed locale - use a
> different locale resolution strategy

So basically FixedLocaleResolver is for cases when you want to upfront disable the possibility of changing locale in your application.